# A result related to generating functions I am unable to prove.

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, generating-functions

I am unable to think about how to prove this result related to generating functions.

> Let $\{a_n\}_{n=0}^\infty$ be an infinite sequence and $b_n = \sum_{i=0}^n a_i $. Let $G_a(x)$  be the generating function for $\{a_n\}$ and $G_b(x)$ be the generating function for $\{b_n\}$. Prove that $G_a(x) = (1-x) G_b(x)$ .

Can someone please tell how to prove this result.

Comment: @ViktorGlombik I tried putting value $b_n$=$\sum_{i=0}^n a_i $ into $G_a (x) $=$\sum_{n=0 }^{\infty} a_n  x^n $ . but after that I am unable to think how to proceed!! Can you please help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**HINT**

change the order of summations
$$
G_b(x)
 = \sum_{n=0}^\infty b_n x^n
 = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \left(\sum_{i=0}^n a_i\right) x^n
 = \sum_{i=0}^\infty a_i \left(\sum_{n=i}^\infty x^n\right)
 = \sum_{i=0}^\infty a_i x^i \left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n\right)
$$
Can you finish it now?